# Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Invalid policy syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to set up an S3 bucket policy in Terraform. I have written the following code in a module `core/main.tf`:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "access_to_bucket" {

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.some_bucket.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action    = ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectAcl", "s3:ListBucket"]
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = "${var.some_variable_name}"
        Resource = [
          "${aws_s3_bucket.some_bucket.arn}",
          "${aws_s3_bucket.some_bucket.arn}/*"
        ]
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

Which then gets instantiated in a local module which uses localstack to run locally.

This is the plan generated:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.local.aws_s3_bucket_policy.access_to_bucket will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "access_to_bucket" {
      + bucket = "some_bucket"
      + id     = (known after apply)
      + policy = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action    = [
                          + "s3:GetObject",
                          + "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                          + "s3:ListBucket",
                        ]
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Principal = "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/test_role"
                      + Resource  = [
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/*",
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket",
                        ]
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
    }
╷
│ Error: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Invalid policy syntax.
│       status code: 400, request id, host id
│ 
│   with module.local.aws_s3_bucket_policy.access_to_bucket,
│   on ../core/main.tf line 55, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "access_to_bucket":
│   55: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "access_to_bucket" {
│
```

Running it both locally and in AWS ends up with this error. I am guessing it's a syntax error somewhere but AFAIK this is correct. Any clue what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Principal` isn't valid. If you look at the IAM user guide (S3 bucket policies share the same syntax but are limited to actions on the bucket and combine to form a least privilege access control) on [the Principal element](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html) you should see examples such as this:

```json
"Principal" : { 
"AWS": [ 
  "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root",
  "arn:aws:iam::555555555555:root" 
  ]
}
```

This allows the IAM action to happen only for users or roles in the two AWS accounts with IDs `123456789012` and `555555555555`.

In your case you want to allow [an IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-roles) so your policy should look like this:

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/test_role"},
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectAcl", "s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/*", "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Terraform allows you to write the JSON for your IAM policies yourself, which can be easier to compare to examples across the internet, or you can use the [`aws_iam_policy_document` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) which will give you more plan time validation as Terraform can better understand the structure you are giving it.

The equivalent policy document as above but as an `aws_iam_policy_document` data source looks like this:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "bucket_policy" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/test_role"]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:GetObjectAcl",
      "s3:ListBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket",
      "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/*",
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "access_to_bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.some_bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.bucket_policy.json
}
```